# Passing boolean parameter to stored procedure with Mybatis

Tags: java, spring, plsql, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am trying to call Oracle PL/SQL procedure with Mybatis in Spring project. However I am getting below error: 
**Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to**

Problem is with boolean parameter because when I remove it it works well. (process_now parameter is optional in procedure) The stored procedure works well when I am calling it with SQL Developer.

```
 <select id="processUser" statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="UserResult">
 CALL myprocedure(
            user_id => #{userId, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=IN},
            description => #{description, jdbcType=VARCHAR, mode=IN},
            process_now => #{processNow, jdbcType=BOOLEAN, mode=IN},
            response => #{response, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=OUT}
        )
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: In your example, you are missing the `#` in front of the parameter for process_now.

Comment: I missed it while copying and pasting it here. In the code, there is no problem with #

Comment: It would probably help to turn on logging and see the prepared SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by creating new custom wrapper procedure and declaring boolean variables within it. Then I passed those declared variables to my original procedure. That solved my problem.

Here is the link to page: (Read 'Wrapping PL/SQL BOOLEAN, RECORD, and TABLE Types' part)
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64684/typesup1.htm